# gevent: I/O completes before timeout, but timeout still occurs

Tags: python, timeout, gevent

I have two greenlets. The first greenlet starts a 7-second timeout before firing off a HTTP request that I know will take 5 seconds to complete. The second greenlet is doing some CPU-bound task (simulated by `time.sleep`) that takes 10 seconds to complete. The code:

```
from gevent import monkey; monkey.patch_socket()

import time

import gevent
import requests


def f1():
    try:
        with gevent.Timeout(7):
            print "f1: downloading our page in 5 seconds"
            requests.get('http://httpbin.org/delay/5')
    except gevent.Timeout:
        print "Timed out."
    else:
        print "Finished!"


def f2():
    print "f2: being greedy for 10 seconds"
    time.sleep(10)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    g1 = gevent.spawn(f1)
    g2 = gevent.spawn(f2)
    gevent.joinall([g1, g2])
```

When I run this code, the timeout gets triggered, even though I know the HTTP request was finished:

```
$ python test.py
f1: downloading our page in 5 seconds
f2: being greedy for 10 seconds
Timed out.
```

The `time.sleep` call is obviously responsible for the timeout, but I don't actually care how long that takes. What I really wanted to limit was the duration of the HTTP request.

Is there any way to write this code so that the timeout only occurs if the HTTP request is not done? Is there a way to deal with the I/O event first before the timeout event?

Answer (score 0):

NB - Blocking calls - like CPU bound functions - should not be assigned to greenlets as by definition they would block all other greenlets from running.

Use a combination of a native thread pool like one provided by `gevent.threadpool.ThreadPool` for blocking tasks and greenlets for non-blocking tasks.

The behaviour in the example code is because the code is not patching time and `time.sleep(10)` is causing gevent to timeout as it blocks the entire event loop, meaning for all greenlets.

This works as expected:

```
from gevent import monkey
monkey.patch_all()

import time

import gevent
import requests


def f1():
    try:
        with gevent.Timeout(7):
            print "f1: downloading our page in 5 seconds"
            requests.get('http://httpbin.org/delay/5')
    except gevent.Timeout:
        print "Timed out."
    else:
        print "Finished!"


def f2():
    print "f2: being greedy for 10 seconds"
    time.sleep(10)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    g1 = gevent.spawn(f1)
    g2 = gevent.spawn(f2)
    gevent.joinall([g1, g2])
```

Output:

```
f1: downloading our page in 5 seconds
f2: being greedy for 10 seconds
Finished!
```

Can also use `gevent.sleep` to avoid patching time.

Comment: I'm using `time.sleep` because I'm trying to simulate a CPU-bound task, which would indeed block the entire event loop. But you've got me thinking that maybe I shouldn't be doing such things in the event loop in the first place -- probably the kind of thing that `gevent.threadpool` is meant for.

Comment: Quite. Blocking tasks do not belong in greenlets as they would block the entire event loop. Use a combination of a thread pool for blocking or CPU bound functions and greenlets for non-blocking calls.